# What happens when I level up?

Tags: borderlands-2

A notice on your first level says that health and damage increases with every level. By how much? Does it differ by class? And what else? Is it always one skill point per level? Do other stats change?

Comment: From level 5 onwards only one skill point per level. Other stats? Stuff like reload and runnning speed is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes, and the numbered specifics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running speed, reload speed and pretty much everything is constant, and does not grow on its own.
It can be improved via Badass Ranks/Tokens by amount explicitly stated there.

> Base health appears to follow the exponential function Health =
>   floor(80 * 1.13^level) In other words, each level increases your base
>   Health by 13% relative to the previous level. Equivalently, your base
>   Health doubles every 5.67 levels. At level 50, your base Health is
>   36058.

[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Health#Borderlands_2)

Your damage does not increase itself, but there's a sliding scale that determines damage to targets of different levels. Thus, after you level up, you start to do more damage to a constant enemy of constant level. [Here](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Damage#Enemy_level)'s the scale for BL1, I could not find one for BL2, maybe it's the same.

Comment: Do you also have a source for the statement that everything else isn't level related? (I think it isn't, at least nothing was in borderlands 1). But you know, [citation needed] ;)

Comment: Ahah, so that's how they enforce level disparity even if you have really good guns.

Comment: Nope, no explicit sources yet. It is easily testable, though, so someone'll do that soon.

Comment: Well, the level disparity only works one way. If you are higher level than a enemy, you do not suddenly start to do more damage. I think you do take less damage from them. But your dps against them does not go up. Source: Sniper hit 131 damage. *Ding*. next sniper hit 131 damage.

Comment: That's new, thanks! In BL1 damage did multiply up to 2x at level +5 or something...

Answer (score 0):

Also, "level up bonus is 100% more Damage for 60 seconds and full health."

Source(s): http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=4849229&postcount=4 & [www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2YYwM1coOU#t=35m13s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2YYwM1coOU#t=35m13s)