# How can I beat Hyperius the invincible?

Tags: borderlands-2

So two friends and I (2 sirens with Res, one gunzerker) have been trying to kill Hyperious for a couple hours. At best we could get him down to about 1/4th health.

We have The Bee and the Conference call and we know to res each other, we know to stay spread out, but his AOE "nuke" attack is *so* long range.

We're thinking the trick must have to do with Aggression management and his robots. Once you kill all 4 robots he's vulnerable, but still hard to kill and his aggro seems random; even with 2 Sirens we couldn't make sure everyone stayed alive. It's not that we healed too slowly (our phaselock came active almost instantly) but at some point it'd always wind up that both Sirens were down, and if the Gunzerker tried to res one of us, half the time he got taken out too.

Also, the Bee seems oddly useless against him. I know the bee *itself* hasn't been nerfed, but the damage boost seems useless in this fight, even when the shield is up. Is this due to the shields or some special property of the boss or what?

So what do we do with his robots? Leave one alive, shoot Hyperious when his shield is down, kill all the robots ASAP or what? What team should I have? Do we really need 4 Sirens with healing spec?

How can we kill Hyperious?

Comment: Bee + CC (any shot gun actually) got nerfed recently (in relativity to question asked date), so a better weapons will have to be used. The Gunzerker could go GrogNozzle + Unkempt Harold (DP).

Answer (score 8):

The way I have beat him in co-op was with myself as Maya and my friend as Axton. Axton used his turret with bubble shield at the start which blocks the first blasts fully and I was throwing the baby maker at hyperious with the bee equipped took him down to half health. Then you just need to keep stopping his bots from connecting to him so he can't use the blast or have his shield, we both used conference calls for this save your SMG ammo until he hasn't got a shield.

Try to get a relic to boost tediore dmg and try to keep the bots alive as long as possible but you will eventually have to kill them all. When this happens Axton should throw down turrets to attract him (hopefully, worked for us) then throw your baby maker and you should have him dead. By the time we killed all the bots he had less then a quarter of his health left so it wasn't too bad with him jumping around. Dropped some bad loot though :(

Comment: Bad loot like "Terramorphous" bad? We were sort of afraid he'd probably give loot just as bad as Terra despite being >100x harder

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you don't have access to the Bee and/or Baby Maker, or do not want to use those combos:

1. Have a full group with a variety of characters and useful team bonuses whenever possible.  One of your members should be a Siren with a strong (Angelic) Nurse class mod that is going to be your primary healer, which should give everyone 220 to 240 health regen/sec.  Having Axton with Phalanx Shield Turrets is also *highly* recommended (Grit wouldn't be bad either, even if it only works against the Novas some of the time).  High-capacity shields with short recharge delays are also *highly* recommended on your non-healers... note that this excludes the Bee.
2. Your healer is going to stand next to the pipe that is just to your left when you enter through the gate.  The job of the other players is to keep Hyperious and his minions pathed to the left of the pipe so they do not gain LOS (Line of Sight) on your healer.  This means trying to keep him away from where you entered, but not heading toward the back of the arena.

   Note that If you head too far back, the uneven landscape will prevent your healer from getting LOS for Res, and it is too far of a run to be safe for them to expose themselves.  In theory, a sniping Zer0 could hang back with your healer, but you're severely increasing the chances of Hyperious moving into LOS on your healer and ruining the strategy, and to keep both of them out of LOS would require getting Hyperious to track to a much more specific area.
3. Pay attention to Hyperious' animation and audio cues. He telegraphs his Nova attack with both, giving Axton time to throw down his shielded turret (barely), and giving your healer time to duck back behind the pipe which will block the Nova attacks.
4. Immediately post-Novas, the healer should use Res on any distant party members that need to be raised while she or Axton (if he survived) work on saving any remaining downed party members.
5. The healer needs to rush back to cover, and anyone needing health restored (hopefully not too much) quickly should move to the opposite side of the pipe where the gap allows the healer to shoot/heal them back to full health.
6. Repeat this process doing as much damage as possible to Hyperious when he is exposed, including your healer who should be able to attack him between Novas rounds by stepping just outside of cover (but be careful of his minions while they are still up).
7. Once Hyperious' minions are down... unload everything you have at him but your healer should not step out of cover anymore unless it is to Res, and should focus on keeping everyone's health up between Nova rounds which will come more frequently.

Other Notes:

- I have heard from others, but not verified myself, that Hyperious can be staggered when he is preparing his Nova attack, which prevents him from using the attack.  Sorry to say I don't know exactly how this functions, but it probably requires critting with a certain amount of damage.  This may be a way for Salvadore, Zer0, or Gaige to assist in an "offensive defense".
- Gaige has a potentially great build if you can get ahold of a level 50 Law (Pistol with bonus melee damage), level 50 Order (Roid Shield).  Combined, they give Gaige healing via melee attacks. Have her use the Slayer of Terramorphus class mod (or whatever else allows her to max out Anarchy stacks at 600), and a relic that either raises maximum health or melee damage.  Spec her through the Anarchy tree all the way down to "With Claws" (which gives an Anarchy-based boost to melee damage [+360% at 600 Anarchy] and more melee healing) and get Discord along the way (reload early for healing... slowly consumes Anarchy), make sure to also take the "Cooking Up Trouble" skill which gives health regen as long as your magazine is full (since you won't really be shooting with Law it's a constant regen).

  If the party Siren is using Angelic Nurse class mod, Gaige will have access to thousands of health/sec healing while meleeing (but it will degrade over time as her Anarchy goes down).  She should begin the fight already charged with 600 stacks of Anarchy.  She should begin using melee attacks against Hyperious, which will eat one stack of her Anarchy per hit (but for huge damage), then when his shields go up, switch weapons to something with a small magazine to build Anarchy back (preferably something corrosive) against the minions.  Whenever Hyperious is going to use his Novas, fire Law once and reload to activate Dischord and start extra healing, after both Novas go off (assuming you survive), fire Law again and reload to deactive Dischord, and resume melee attacks to refill health.

Admittedly, my Gaige is not ready for Hyperious yet, so I haven't proven this build against him... but on paper it certainly looks like if she can get her max HP high enough that she should be able to melee/heal through the Novas.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

So, if you're not above being cheap (and after a few fights against this guy, you won't be), you can use the Baby Maker to make him die like nothing:

The trick is to hit him fast with several Tediore explosive reloads before his shield is up. He only turns aggressive and spawns a shield after taking damage, and you get enough time to murder him with this gun. Bring full ammo. This makes him only slightly less trivial than [Terramorphous with The Bee and Conference Call](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86620/11920).

The Baby Maker drops from Madame von Bartlesby, the large Varkid boss in the southwest of Tundra Express, after you've beaten her for Tiny Tina's mission. It's an orange/legendary Tediore Submachine gun.

Comment: Please note that the Conference Call method has been patched.  "Amp Shields have their Amp damage amount divided among the projectiles from multi-projectile weapons (all weapons with a yellow multiplier in the Damage stat), thus making all Amp shields, including the Bee, less effective on shotguns and other multi-projectile weapons" Reference: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bee#Notes

Answer (score 0):

You can stagger him with zero by shooting through his robots into him, I forget the skill name but it does stop his Nova Blast and it hurts him pretty good.

Comment: I believe that's b0re, but I'm not a Zero player

Answer (score 0):

The easiest trick to beat Hyperius is to use the Evil Masher Glitch/Exploit.  It hasn't been patched yet, but it's been around a long time.  Basically, the Evil Masher is an assault rifle with sub-par stats, a reward from Marcus's mission (Kai).

When reloading however, there is a chance to "power up" the weapon. Taken from the BL Wikia:

> There are at least six possible outcomes to Evil Smasher reloading:
>
> - Power up level 1, indicated by the power-up sound and explosion. Slight increase in power and reduced recoil for bullets in the next
>     clip. No change in clip size.
> - Power up level 2, indicated by a louder power-up sound cue, and explosion larger than that of level 1. All round improved weapon stats
>     compared with level 1. In particular next clip increases in size to
>     about 30.
> - Power up level 3, louder cues than level 2, high stats than level 2, in particular clip size increases to about 50.
> - Power up level 4, the previous trend continues. All round improvement to level 3, in particular clip size increases to about 70.
> - Power up level 5, similar as before but bigger and better. In particular clip size increases to about 90.
> - Nothing. No sound or explosion. Weapon returns to base stats for the next clip.

As for the glitch:

> As soon as the power-up sound and visual cue occur on Evil Smasher,
>   and if player swap Evil Smasher right away, the power-up effects of
>   Evil Smasher will now apply to the newly swapped weapon, and stacks on
>   top of the weapon's other properties. ALL weapons in active slots now
>   inherit ALL of Evil Smasher's special property of powering up (i.e.
>   chance to power-up after reload, with same explosion and power-up
>   sound).
>
> Take this example. Say when reloading Evil Smasher, the cues indicate
>   the next clip with be at the highest power-up level. If the player
>   switches immediately to, say, Infinity, before Evil Smasher finishes
>   reloading, Infinity now has increased clip size, improved damage, fire
>   rate and recoil reduction proportional to Evil Smasher highest
>   power-up level. Even though the normal Infinity property of having
>   clip size of 1 is "overwritten" by Evil Smasher power-up, Infinity's
>   other original properties (never using ammo and bullet spread looks
>   like infinity symbol) remain.
>
> When combined with the Infinity repeater pistol in the stated manner
>   and The Bee, and due to the dramatical increase to fire rate, the
>   player can kill any of the Invincible foes in a matter of seconds
>   (usually less than five seconds, even on True Vault Hunter Mode). For
>   example, Voracidous the Invincible can be killed before Chief Ngwatu
>   spawns, and Hyperius the Invincible even before his loader minions
>   have time to make it invulnerable. This exploit has, as such, game
>   breaking effects. Also, when using this glitch with Voracidous, he
>   will instantly respawn after going outside of the fightning area,
>   without the need to pay Eridium again or rezone.
>
> This power-up effect applies to all weapons in active slots until the
>   current game session ends, or switching back to Evil Smasher. It does
>   not go away even after respawn, fast travel or entering inventory
>   menu. In multiplayer session, the clip count may reset to base stat
>   after fast travel, still all Evil Smasher properties remain.
>
> This glitch is most noticeable for weapons with low clip count, such
>   as Rocket Launcher and Sniper Rifle. Rocket Launcher under this glitch
>   can easily have clip size above 27, more than the maximum a normal
>   backpack can hold

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I see alot of people are having trouble beating Hyperious and I don't really get it. Ive beaten him on single player and multiplayer on the first try. The first time I beat him on single player I was using a level 36 Psycho with all skill points invested in the Mmania skill tree. All I did was kill his 4 protectors and start shooting him repeatedly. As soon as my health got to critical I would activate "Realease the Beast" and begin throwing buzz axes at him while running away untill it wore off then shoot him some more untill my health got back to critical amd repeat. I used this method to beat him in single player and to finish him off when all my teammates died in multiplayer. The guns I used were "Potent Aegis" to kill his minions "Swiss Splatgun" for general damage and the "Ultraprecise Bazooka" for extra damage. He seems to go down on the first try everytime. Also when throwing buzz axes you have about a 25% chance to stagger hyperious no matter what hes doing, anything from jumping to that nuke attack he does can be staggered with enough speed and precision.

Comment: Also, if your playing on normal mode it only takes about 40k damage to stagger him. But each 40k hit only has about 25% chance of doing this.