# Is there a quick way to defeat Master Gee?

Tags: borderlands-2

Turns out [there's a cheap, quick way to beat Hyperious the Invincible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89212/how-can-i-beat-hyperious-the-invincible/89320#89320). However neither the Baby Maker trick (thow lots of strong explosive reloads) or The Bee & Conference Call combo seem to work against [Master Gee The Invincible](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Gee_The_Invincible).

In fact, the only apparent way to kill Gee is to "kite" him for 10+ minutes, making him
walk into little pools of acid until he slowly dies. Is there a faster way to deal with him
or is that really the only way to defeat him?

The fastest I've seen him killed is about 8 minutes:

While this is relatively impressive, he'd need to die in a couple minutes max to be remotely appealing to fight due to how quickly Hyperious can be taken down (even counting the robots).

Comment: @desaivv that is [quite literally the majority of the fight](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VqCUN_M4G0)

Comment: He's called "... the Invincible". I'd expect him to be bloody hard. Hell, I'm impressed you even beat him (not really, this is Borderlands after all)!

Comment: I haven't gotten to the level of being able to fight him yet (I still have to get to level 50) but why couldn't you just shock him to bring down the shield? Or possibly use corrosive weapons? Are those worms the only way he can be damaged?

Comment: @JeffMercado I haven't fought him either, but it sounds like he is either practically or literally invincible to bullet damage until the shield is down

Answer (score 2):

Master Gee has an almost impenetrable shield 4x Conference Call + Bee shields won't make a dent. In fact the Bee is a very bad idea as it's almost impossible to not be taking damage for most of this fight.

Baby Maker reloads aren't much use either. The only thing that seems to hurt Gee's shield in any useful way is his own worms.

Master Gee spawns sand worms - one at a time at first, but more and more as the fight continues.

Each worm that you kill produces a fountain of corrosion on the spot where it died. If you do nothing about this a pool of corrosion will spread out from it until it fills the entire arena and you'll be taking constant corrosion damage.

The only way to get rid of the fountain of corrosion is for it to be absorbed, either by a player (normally an instant FFYL) or by Master Gee (the only way to kill his shields).

So this fight is always about kiting, luring, singularity/phase-lock pulling, or otherwise getting Gee to run through the middle of the fountain left by the last sand worm killed before too many others spawn.

If you end up with two fountains too far apart then your fight is usually over - one or the other is going to spread until the constant DPS kills everyone.

In a word: annoying.

Is there a quick way to kill him? No, I'm pretty sure he's been designed to be very tough to defeat no matter how levelled/kitted up the team taking him on is.

That said I've seen him killed in a single shot by a level 999 player who was obviously hacked, but I'd [avoid hackers and public games until the graveyard exploit's fixed](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=180735).

Answer (score 0):

not sure about a quick way, but a good Neogenator Shield that spawns with an 84% elemental resistance is probably the best shield to use during the fight with Master Gee, along with a Vitality Relic for max-health increase, or a modified Tenacity Relic for increased FFYL time and an increase in Second Wind Health

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to kill master gee instantly. Yes I said instantly. Any character is good but I recommend Salvador. You need singularity grenades and the skill a fistful of hurt. It uppercuts enemies launching them back. Any singularity will do but longbow is the best delivery. 
Step 1: Stand outside of the arena and throw singularities to pull gee towards the gate. (If you stand in the ring the fight will start)
Step 2: after pulling Gee close to the gate throw a singularity at the alcove to the left of the gate. This will put him right in the corner of the gate.
Step 3: start the fight by shooting him. Use fistful of hurt to knock his annoying ass into the gate. The gate will crush him and kill him instantly.
Step 4: Collect your loot. Also you still get he seraph crystals and a chance to receive the ayah rocket launcher.
Step 5: repeat as many times as your heart desires.

Answer (score 0):

I killed him on my own at level 51, no weird method, just had the place full of green, kept out the way of his attacks, sent the deathtrap out to draw his fire and kill worms, and when my health started dropping, threw a transfusion grenade when necessary. I didn't get any crystals though... Unless I missed them. I picked up all the loot though.