# How do you get inside this area at Washburne Refinery?

Tags: borderlands-2

In this area there is a door with a lever and behind it seems to be some sort of arena. 
During my normal first playthrough, this door was locked and the lever unfunctional.

**How do you get inside and what is there to do?**

[image: Image of Area]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This arena is where **Hyperius the Invincible** stands around all day waiting for challengers. You will receieve a quest for this boss after beating all the story missions in the Scarlett DLC.

He's level 50+ and it's a very hard fight, for some tips on how to beat it check out [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89212/how-can-i-beat-hyperious-the-invincible).